# Action of the basis element $H \in sl_2(\mathbb{C})$ on vector space $V$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Action of the basis element $H \in sl_2(\mathbb{C})$ on vector space $V$ is diagonalizable

I'm reading about the representations of lie algebra $sl_2(\mathbb{C})$ and it says that the preservation of the Jordan decomposition implies that the action of $H$ on $V$ is diagonalizable. $H$ is the 2x2 matrix with $1$ in the top left, $-1$ in the bottom right and 0's elsewhere.

What does it mean that the Jordan decomposition is preserved? And how does this imply that the action of $H$ on $V$ is diagonalizable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jordan-Chevalley decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition) of a matrix is $x=x_s+x_n$, where $x_s$ is semisimple (so, over $\mathbb{C}$, that means diagonalizable) and $x_n$ is nilpotent (so, strictly upper triangular in some basis). The parts $x_s$ and $x_n$ are both polynomials in $x$, so they commute.

If $\phi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a lie algebra representation, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is itself a linear lie algebra (i.e. its elements are matrices and its lie bracket is the commutator bracket) which is also semisimple, then $\phi$ preserves the decomposition, i.e. the semisimple and nilpotent parts $\phi(x)_s$ and $\phi(x)_n$ of $\phi(x)$ are just $\phi(x_s)$ and $\phi(x_n)$ respectively.

Here, since $H$ is diagonalizable, its nilpotent part is zero, so the nilpotent part of $\pi(H)$ is also zero,  so the matrix $\pi(H)$ is also diagonalizable.

Comment: Does the fact that $x_s$ and $x_n$ commute come into play here?? Could I see that they commute just based on the fact that one is diagonalizable and the other is strictly upper triangle? When you say that they are polynomials in $x$, do you mean some indeterminant $x$ not yet mentioned or the original matrix $x=x_s+x_n$. THanks for your answer, this website is great!

Comment: (1) No, commutativity isn't used here. (2) Not the way you're phrasing it - you would need to use the fact $x_s$ is diagonal & $x_n$ is strictly upper triangular wrt the same basis (not just that $x_s$ is diagonalizable). (3) I mean $x_s$ and $x_n$ are polynomials of the matrix $x$. (It wouldn't make sense to be a polynomial of an indeterminate...)

Comment: What do you mean by $x_s$ and $x_n$ are both polynomials in $x$, and thus they commute? It seems to me that $x$ is a matrix and can be expressed as a sum with $x_s$ and $x_n$ as summands. Also, I guess there doesn't need to be a basis such that makes $x_s$ diagonal and $x_n$ nilpotent at the same time, huh? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I mean there exist polynomials $P$ and $Q$ such that $x_s=P(x)$ and $x_n=Q(x)$, and thus we may conclude $x_sx_n=x_nx_s$ (indeed all three of $x,x_s,x_n$ commute). This is proved using the Chinese Remainder Theorem on the Wikipedia page.